# Octave -- Plotting a tan function

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

While reading a tutorial on Octave I found the following line of code that produces a sin plot:

```
fplot (@sin, [-10, 10]);
```

I decided I wanted to plot tan instead of sin so I entered the following command:

```
fplot (@tan, [-10, 10]);
```

When I did this I got the following plot:
[image]

Why did I get that graph instead of one of a tan function?  How can I plot a tan function?

Comment: This problem is not reproducible in *MATLAB* (atleast in *2016a* and *2016b*) .  *MATLAB 2016a* and *2016b* give this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/89Lb9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to plot tan from -10..10. This function goes to +/-inf (for example tan(pi/2)) so the autoscale tries to plot from -inf to inf...

Try setting the limits manually:

```
fplot (@tan, [-10, 10]);
set (gca, 'ylim', [-10 10])
```

[image: tan plot]

or adapt your limits:

```
fplot (@tan, [-0.9 * pi/2, 0.9 * pi/2]);
```

Comment: Ahhh, if I plot a whole bunch of points like with fplot(@tan, [-10, 10], 1000) shouldn't I see some points that aren't going towards inf though?  Like it may be going from -inf to inf, but if there are enough points shouldn't some of them not be approaching -inf or inf and show up on the graph?

Comment: They show up, don't you see the vertical lines at pi/2 + n*pi? Also think about aliasing, or anti-aliasing in this case